# Insert values from two gridviews into one sql column with Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

NET web form page and I am attempting to pass values from two different gridviews into a single sql column. I am still new to parameterized querys so I am not to sure what the syntax would be for this. Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly apperciated. 
My obvioulsy broken code is below

```
void AddIEKGNote()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < EKGImpGV.Rows.Count; y++)
        {
            try
            {
                String qry = "sp_InsertPatientNoteCarotidDuplexImp";
                com.Open();
                SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand(qry, com);
                con.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", EKGImpGV.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);
                con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", GridView3.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);
                con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_T", Label22.Text.Trim());
                con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ID", Label6.Text.Trim());
                j = con.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write(" SUCCESS ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write(" ERROR ! ");
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                com.Close();
                EKGReportReader();
                SearchData();
                BaseEKG();
                PostEKG();
                ImpressionReader1();
                ImpressionReader2();
                ImpressionReader3();
                ImpressionReader4();
                ImpressionReader5();
                ImpressionReader6();
            }
        }
    }
```

This will not work since I am trying to pass Value twice in this function and my stored procedure and my sql table only has one "Value" column.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", EKGImpGV.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text , GridView3.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);
```

Comment: Why not declaring new SQL variable to hold second GridView value? Then you can use something like if-condition to check if value between them exists.

Comment: Yeah I think that will be my second option. I was hoping there was a quicker fix lol. I could also just creat another procedure to insert the value from Gridview3 into the same table EKGImpGV is pointing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", EKGImpGV.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", GridView3.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);
```

with this

```
string val = EKGImpGV.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text + GridView3.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text;
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", val);
```

Comment: Great idea! Didn't even think about making them into a string value! 
Much appreciated